# Getting exception while running adb commands programmatically

Tags: java, android, adb

I am trying to get list of adb devices through code but getting an exception when starting the ProcessBuilder.

**Here is my Code -->**

```
try {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb.exe", "adb devices");
                pb.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools"));

                Process p = pb.start(); // here is the xception
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
                String line = null;  

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)(\\s+)(device)");
                Matcher matcher;

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                    if (line.matches(pattern.pattern())) {
                        matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                        if (matcher.find())
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                    }
                }
```

**Here is the Exception stacktrace -->**

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb.exe" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"):
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)    at
>   MainTest.Example.main(Example.java:45) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)   ... 2 more

I have tried after changing commands in ProcessBuilder but no luck.

Need help please.

Answer (score 3):

this should work

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\<your user name>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe", "adb devices");
```

Do not forget:
 `<your user name>` - set your name

or put `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\` into windows `PATH` variable.

Comment: Now I can see adb.exe is started in Task Manager but it seems adb devices command is not executed and flow is stuck at `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)`.

Comment: @vv88 , first of all , change  `new ProcessBuilder("adb.exe", "adb devices");` into ` new ProcessBuilder("adb.exe", "adb","devices");`

Comment: I have change it to `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\vv88\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe", "adb", "devices");` but still stuck at same point. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @vv88 does simple `pb.waitFor()` works? or it hands too?

Comment: I have put `p.waitFor()` after `pb.start()`. As per javadoc waitFor() method will wait untill process represented by p is not terminated. So now I am stuck at `p.waitFor()'.

Comment: try to write into stdin: `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));writer.write("\n");writer.flush();writer.close();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133646/discussion-between-vv88-and-vyacheslav).

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of help and suggestions from Vyacheslav over the chat here is the working solution for the community -->

```
try 
            {

                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\<Your User Name Here>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe", "devices");

                //pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // can use these 2 line if you want to see output or errors in file.
                //pb.redirectOutput(new File("C:/pbOutput.Txt"));

                Process p = pb.start();

                while(p == null)
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                String line = null;  

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)(\\s+)(device)");
                Matcher matcher;


                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                    if (line.matches(pattern.pattern())) {
                        matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                        if (matcher.find())
                            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                    }
                }  
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I just need to find out why "adb devices" did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This will for mac If yor are using zsh :

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"zsh", "-l", "-c", commands})

in commands we can pass "adb devices" or another commands

At my end its working